# cant automate calendar in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, calendar

I 'm trying to automate a calendar with selenium, but cant find a way through, structure of the calendar html is like this:

[image: img]

6 divs containing a tags of each day, some days are disabled
like this:

[image: calendar]

my take on this is that i'll select all non disabled a tags and look over then and if elem.text is equal to the certain date which i'll provide in function as a parameter, selenium will select that date
this is my code for this:

```
    def pick_date(self, date, month, year):
        month_status = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="caltitle"]')))
        _month, _year = (month_status.text).split()
        next_month_btn = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="next-month"]')))
        all_active_dates = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="calweeks"]/div')
        print(_month, _year)
        for i, week_row in enumerate(all_active_dates):
            for day in week_row.find_elements(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="calweeks"]/div[{i + 1}]/a[not(@attr="caldisabled") and not(@attr="caloff")]'):
                if day.text == date:
                    day.click()
                print(day.text)
```

however `for day in week_row.find_elements(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="calweeks"]/div[{i + 1}]/a[not(@attr="caldisabled") and not(@attr="caloff")]')`

this is selecting all the a tags and not only the non disables
output is something like this:

```
June 2022
29
30
31
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

any help would be appreciated, coz i am bashing my head on this issue for soo long.

Comment: can you share a link to the website with calendar?

Comment: https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/

Comment: tweetdeck calendar scheduling

Comment: @AndreyKotov sir i am waiting for ur help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all active elements:

```
all_active_dates = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="calweeks"]//a[not(contains(@class,'caldisabled')) and not(contains(@class,'caloff'))]')
```

and then just enumerate through `all_active_dates` and simply `print(active_date.text)`

Comment: so there is no need for nested loop like looping per week as i did there

Comment: yep, just use foreach loop. I am not a python user but it will be something like: for active_date in all_active_dates: print(active_date.text)

Comment: oaky ill try that and let you know